# Asdocs seems unable to find embedded assets

Tags: apache-flex

I'm running asdocs from a .bat file with flex sdk 3.2.0 (I have replaced my long project root folder with *PROJECTROOT*):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.2.0\bin\asdoc" -source-path . "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.2.0" "_PROJECTROOT_\Components\src" "C:\_PROJECTROOT_\assets" -doc-sources .
PAUSE"
```

Unforunately, I keep getting errors similar to this:

```
"_PROJECTROOT_\assets\styles.css(344): Error: Invalid Embed directive in stylesheet - can't resolve source 'Embed(source = "close_button.png")'.

downSkin: Embed(source="close_button.png");"
```

I really don't understand this as "close_button.png" is in the same folder as styles.css. When I build the project from within flexbuilder, it compiles it fine and does not throw any errors.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's not using your folder with the CSS as the root folder when it's working. It's looking for the assets in the folder you are running the commands from.

Try adding the assets folder to your source path.

Comment: The relative paths in the css document should be relative to the path of that documents? I have tried putting my assets folder inside the source path folder (where my main mxml document is). I also tried putting the asset folder contents inside the source path folder. The errors are the same as before.

Comment: unless the actual assets are at the same level, you'd have to reference them by source="assets/close_button.png".

You need to add a second path to your source-path element to refer to the exact folder where assets are.

Comment: Hi Gregor. The assets are in the exact same folder as styles.css, namely "C:\_PROJECTROOT_\assets".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and an answer I found elsewhere indicated to put a slash at the beginning of the asset path. That is, instead of

```
Embed(source="close_button.png")
```

rather

```
Embed(source="/close_button.png")
```