# ASDoc transcodde

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, asdoc

I've been trying for hours to find a solution this problem but have not been able to.

I'm trying to run ASDoc with the following command:

```
asdoc -doc-sources
 "C:\My Projects\TheProject\Flex\TheProject\src" -main-title TheProject
 -output "c:\My Projects\TheProject\Flex\TheProject"\asdoc -warnings=false
```

I get the following errors:

```
Loading configuration file C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks\4
.5.1\frameworks\flex-config.xml
C:\My Projects\TheProject\Flex\TheProject\src\com\company\common\comp
onents\Header.mxml: Error: unable to resolve '/com/company/common/co
mponents/images/logo.gif' for transcoding

C:\My Projects\TheProject\Flex\TheProject\src\com\company\common\comp
onents\Header.mxml: Error: Unable to transcode /com/company/common/c
omponents/images/logo.gif.
```

I've tried adding an extra slash as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329224/asdocs-seems-unable-to-find-embedded-assets) but that didn't fix it.

Does anybody know a way around this?  Removing the offending piece of code (an embed) fixes the problem... but obviously I don't want to remove it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will help. But possibly try adding the -source-path argument. Since the embed's are relative url's it may be trying to find the assets from the directory the command is running in rather than the source path.

```
asdoc -source-path "C:\My Projects\TheProject\Flex\TheProject\src"
      -doc-sources "C:\My Projects\TheProject\Flex\TheProject\src"
      -main-title TheProject
      -output "c:\My Projects\TheProject\Flex\TheProject\asdoc" 
      -warnings=false
```

Comment: This is on the correct path. One thing to remember that the ASDoc tool must compile the actual application first (this is how it begins to build it's references for links) then it actually parses for comments. This is also how it generates a property / method map even when they don't have comments.

Comment: I tried the above method _in conjunction_ with the extra slash at the start for the embed (i.e. /com/company etc) and this worked.  Accepting the answer as it helped me.  I'll edit it to let people know that you still have to put the extra slash at the start.